# Trying to get two HTML inputs side by side

Tags: html, css, input

So I've spent some time trying to figure this one out, but I've ended up turning to StackOverflow for help. I'm trying to get my search bar and go button to display on one line and am having trouble doing this.

The html code for the inputs is:

```
  <nav class="sidebar"> 
  <input type="text"  id="search" placeholder="search">
  <input type="button" name="button" value="Go" class="goButton">
  </nav>
```

And the CSS for the two inputs is as follows:

```
#content .sidebar #search {
    width: calc( 100% - 45px );
    border-radius: 0px;
    height: 42px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #333333;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin-bottom: 21px;
}
/* Go button for search*/
#content .sidebar .goButton {
    position: relative;
    top: -48px;
    width: 45px;
    background-color: #BA2022;
    color: #F3EBDE;
    border-style: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-top: 8px;
    border-radius: 0px;
    height: 42px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin-bottom: 21px;
}
```

Can anyone suggest a fix for this? Currently, the inputs display as follows:

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @chipChocolate.py I'm definitely using the HTML I have posted.

Comment: Well, change the css selectors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It gets aligned when the text box is a little smaller and the `margin-top` of the button is removed:

```
#content .sidebar #search {
    width: calc( 100% - 60px );
    border-radius: 0px;
    height: 42px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #333333;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin-bottom: 21px;
}
/* Go button for search*/
#content .sidebar .goButton {
    position: relative;
    width: 45px;
    background-color: #BA2022;
    color: #F3EBDE;
    border-style: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-top: 8px;
    border-radius: 0px;
    height: 42px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin-bottom: 21px;
}
```

FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/s0y93L87/

Comment: I wouldn't say it's stupidly simple, these design matters are always tricky. Your approach is really good and it's responsive.

Answer (score 0):

try put this:

```
#content .sidebar #search {
    border-radius: 0px;
    height: 42px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #333333;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin-bottom: 21px;
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
}

/* Go button for search*/
#content .sidebar .goButton {
    position: relative;
    top: -48px;
    width: 45px;
    background-color: #BA2022;
    color: #F3EBDE;
    border-style: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-radius: 0px;
    height: 48px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin-bottom: 21px;
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few reason why applying`width: calc( 100% - 45px );` to the text input isn't leaving enough room for the 45px-width button:

1. The browser is adding padding to the text input (+2 pixels for left and right padding) (at least in Chrome)
2. The browser is adding a border to the text input (+2 pixels for left and right borders) (at least in Chrome)
3. Because the text input and button are not on the same line, there is a single whitespace character separating them, adding more width.

Define explicit padding and border for the text input so browsers can't reset it, and adjust the 45px to 47px accordingly (to account for left and right 1px borders):

```
#content .sidebar #search {
    border:1px solid #aaa;
    padding:0;
    width: calc( 100% - 47px );
}
```

And remove the whitespace between the two inputs by putting them on the same line in the HTML:

`<input type="text"  id="search" placeholder="search"><input type="button" name="button" value="Go" class="goButton">`

I also removed the `top: -48px` from your `.goButton` CSS.

Using a CSS reset can help eliminate this kind of problem of browsers adding unexpected styles.

Result: http://jsfiddle.net/k305a0jo/1/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried put it inside a table? something like this:

```
<nav class="sidebar">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td class='search'>
                <input type="text" id="search" placeholder="search">
            </td>
            <td class='go'>
                <input type="button" name="button" value="Go" class="goButton">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</nav>




     .sidebar #search {
     width: calc(100%-45px);
     border-radius: 0px;
     height: 42px;
     text-align: center;
     color: #333333;
     font-size: 14px;
 }
 /* Go button for search*/
 .sidebar .goButton {
     top:-48px;
     background-color: #BA2022;
     width:45px;
     color: #F3EBDE;
     border-style: none;
     text-transform: uppercase;
     border-radius: 0px;
     height: 42px;
     text-align: center;
     font-size: 14px;
 }
 td.search {
 }
 td.go {
 }
 tr {
     width: calc(100%);
     margin-bottom: 21px;
 }
```

Here is a jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/yzmkxfa7/4/